SwiftData migration with iCloud and multi-device support
I’m writing test apps using SwiftData. Running migrations locally works fine. But I couldn’t find anything on how to handle a situation, where my local app is running on e.g. ‘MigrationSchemaV2’ and an iOS app is still running on ‘MigrationSchemaV1’ hence needs to be updated before the data migration takes place.
I expect the local migration to be synced to iCloud automatically therefore the iOS app would crash.
I’m looking for documentation, tutorials, best practice or lessons learned in order to understand the basic implementation idea, its dependencies and implications.
